# Dynamic lookup confusion

Tags: autocad

I am new to autocad and am using it for work, at an electrical company. We build panels, and I have been tasked with making the drawings for them.

I am wondering how to make a dynamic lookup table. For example, everywhere I have the placeholder "Well #1" I want to have it replaced with "2-67-2-8". What would be the best way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: The FIND command should do the trick as it allows replacing text.

Comment: It does, thank you! I'm more looking for a solution where I have a table and can update the table once, and all the references to the text updates automatically.